# Capturing a window in Python

Tags: python, opencv, screenshot

I'm currently looking to find a module, or code that would allow me to capture another processes window.

I've tried working with ImageGrab, however that just captures an area of the screen rather than binding to a specific process window. Since I'm working with a small monitor I can't guarantee that something won't lap over onto the captured area of the screen, so sadly the ImageGrab solution isn't good enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using `win32gui`.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import win32gui

hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, r'Window_Title')
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
dimensions = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)

image = ImageGrab.grab(dimensions)
image.show()
```

You could also move the window to a preferred position if a small screen is the problem.
`win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, 0, 0, 500, 700, True)`
see [win32gui.MoveWindow](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/pywin32/win32gui__MoveWindow_meth.html)

Comment: I don't think this solution would work, if the window is accidentally scrolled over or made inactive it will no longer be in the capture space.

Comment: I don't know if there is any such module that would bind to a specific window. Maybe you could try using `SetForegroundWindow()` just before capturing.

Comment: The program would be constantly capturing probably up to a few times a second, this is not viable especially if the program requires to capture multiple windows.