# Python infinite window loop

Tags: python, opencv, window, screen, ui-automation

So basically this script auto farms. But what matters is the code to define the bbox or region. You see when you open the script you are to click on two points on a screen called Define bbox to define the bbox. after that the main function of the script works. But when the Define bbox window is open it shows itself creating an infinite loop.

[image: 1]

Script

```
import random
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
from pynput import mouse, keyboard

class Rod:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Define bbox')
        self.mouse = mouse.Controller()

    def catch(self, *args):
        time.sleep(0.29)
        self.mouse.press(mouse.Button.left)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        self.mouse.release(mouse.Button.left)
        time.sleep(1)

def stop(key):
    if key == 'q':
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        exit()

keyboard.Listener(on_press=stop)

rod = Rod()

cv2.namedWindow("Define bbox", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow("Define bbox", 800, 600)
bbox = []
def on_mouse_click(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global bbox
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        bbox.append((x, y))
        if len(bbox) == 2:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            return
cv2.setMouseCallback("Define bbox", on_mouse_click)

while True:
    screen = np.array(pyautogui.screenshot())
    screen = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    cv2.imshow("Define bbox", screen)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
    elif len(bbox) == 2:
        break

if len(bbox) == 2:
    x1, y1 = bbox[0]
    x2, y2 = bbox[1]
    bbox = {"top": min(y1, y2), "left": min(x1, x2), "width": abs(x2 - x1), "height": abs(y2 - y1)}
    print(f"Bbox defined as: {bbox}")
else:
    print("Error: Bbox not defined")
    exit()

cv2.imshow('programs vision', np.zeros([480, 640, 1]))
cv2.setWindowProperty('programs vision', cv2.WND_PROP_TOPMOST, 1)
cv2.imshow('binary', np.zeros([480, 640, 1]))
cv2.setWindowProperty('binary', cv2.WND_PROP_TOPMOST, 1)

kernel_size = (3, 3)
kernel_el = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, kernel_size)

while True:
    screen = np.array(pyautogui.screenshot(region=(bbox["left"], bbox["top"], bbox["width"], bbox["height"])))
    screen = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    cv2.imshow('programs vision', screen)

    binary = np.zeros((screen.shape[:-1]))
    a = screen[:, :, 0] == screen[:, :, 1]
    b = screen[:, :, 1] == screen[:, :, 2]
    mask = np.logical_and(a, b)
    binary[mask] = 1
    binary = cv2.erode(binary, kernel_el, (-1, -1))
    cv2.imshow('binary', binary)

    average = np.average(binary)
    if average == 0:
        rod.catch()

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

I made the window smaller but that was not enough.

Comment: By the way is there a way to make it not show itself. If not is there any other way to define the bbox

Comment: welcome! please take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

You show the running screen capture to itself. Of course it will show a self-containing image. This is not undesirable.

If you want a picture of the screen from *before* you opened the window, take the screenshot (once) before opening the window.

Comment: If I do that it will only take the screenshot once. But I when I open the game I will auto farm on, it will still be screen and show the file manager where I opened the script. I know you could just put a delay but it is not really what I want to do. So, is there a way to do the window's function without having to show it? Or should I use the same method to define the bbox but without the window? and if so, how?

Comment: I believe I see the issue. you need to figure out what you need to do and when to do it. yes, it's that generic. this is programming. it has got nothing to do with specific libraries. when you want to *select a region*, that's one moment when you do that. when you're done with that, you can close that window and carry on.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to use the win32 and Pillow image grab libraries so that the window displaying what you want will only display that window, though the window you want to display must not be in full screen and the windows should not overlap. So the code would look like this:

```
import random
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
from pynput import mouse, keyboard
import win32gui
from PIL import ImageGrab

class Rod:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Define bbox')
        self.mouse = mouse.Controller()

    def catch(self, *args):
        time.sleep(0.29)
        self.mouse.press(mouse.Button.left)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        self.mouse.release(mouse.Button.left)
        time.sleep(1)

def stop(key):
    if key == 'q':
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        exit()

keyboard.Listener(on_press=stop)

rod = Rod()

hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Roblox')
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
dimensions = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)

cv2.namedWindow("Define bbox", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow("Define bbox", dimensions[2] - dimensions[0], dimensions[3] - dimensions[1])
bbox = []
def on_mouse_click(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global bbox
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        bbox.append((x, y))
        if len(bbox) == 2:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            return
cv2.setMouseCallback("Define bbox", on_mouse_click)

while True:
    image = ImageGrab.grab(dimensions)
    screen = np.array(image)
    screen = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    cv2.imshow("Define bbox", screen)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
    elif len(bbox) == 2:
        break

if len(bbox) == 2:
    x1, y1 = bbox[0]
    x2, y2 = bbox[1]
    bbox = {"top": min(y1, y2), "left": min(x1, x2), "width": abs(x2 - x1), "height": abs(y2 - y1)}
    print(f"Bbox defined as: {bbox}")
else:
    print("Error: Bbox not defined")
    exit()

cv2.imshow('programs vision', np.zeros([480, 640, 1]))
cv2.setWindowProperty('programs vision', cv2.WND_PROP_TOPMOST, 1)
cv2.imshow('binary', np.zeros([480, 640, 1]))
cv2.setWindowProperty('binary', cv2.WND_PROP_TOPMOST, 1)

kernel_size = (3, 3)
kernel_el = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, kernel_size)

while True:
    image = ImageGrab.grab(dimensions)
    screen = np.array(image)
    screen = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    screen = screen[bbox["top"]:bbox["top"]+bbox["height"], bbox["left"]:bbox["left"]+bbox["width"]]
    cv2.imshow('programs vision', screen)

    binary = np.zeros((screen.shape[:-1]))
    a = screen[:, :, 0] == screen[:, :, 1]
    b = screen[:, :, 1] == screen[:, :, 2]
    mask = np.logical_and(a, b)
    binary[mask] = 1
    binary = cv2.erode(binary, kernel_el, (-1, -1))
    cv2.imshow('binary', binary)

    average = np.average(binary)
    if average == 0:
        rod.catch()

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

You can look to this forum for a code snippet [Capturing a window in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782637/capturing-a-window-in-python)